# Install Epson printer

Tags: software-installation, printer

How can I install my Epson xp 322 printer? The regular way doesn't work. After the pop up "lookng for a driver" nothing happens.

Stefan, Norway

Comment: Does this work with a Epson8871DC ( XP-342 343 345 Series ) too ?
WHERE & HOW can I download the matching packages ?

Answer (score 1):

Download the printer packages and install:
ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver), Epson Printer Utility.
Then, open a terminal and go to the folder containing the downloaded files:
1°:ls
2:cd Download
3°: sudo dpkg -i epson-printer-utility_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb, for example.
After instalation, open System Tools, click printers and add printer.
Search for the correct driver and install it.
Probably the printer is already installed.